# php converting formatted int to int

Tags: php, number-formatting

Sorry for asking this but, I cant found a solution that will get this -> 7,000 to 7000.

I'm using intval() and number_format() but it will just give me 7 not 7000.

```
$myVal = '7,000';
echo intval($myVal);
```

this returns 7

same goes with number_format()

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your php installation localized to a country where `,` is the decimal separator?

Comment: Check out your localization for what @Greg said, by the way, are you using Windows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`intval()` won't work with the string you have because of the comma. You can remove the comma by using `str_replace()` and then calling `intval()` like so:

`echo intval(str_replace(',', '', $myVal))`

Answer (score 11):

If you are using PHP >= 5.3 (or have the "intl" extension installed, with at least version 1.0) then you could also use the [`NumberFormatter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) class to parse a locale-specific number.

```
$myVal = '7,000';
$nf = new NumberFormatter("en_EN", NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);

var_dump($nf->parse($myVal, NumberFormatter::TYPE_INT32));

# output: int(7000)
```

If you're using a PHP-version less than 5.3 you're better of using @KevinS. solution.