# how to calculate total in codeigniter using mysql

Tags: html, mysql, codeigniter

This is my database in which I want to calculate total

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->select_sum('total_sale');
    $query = $this->db->get('one_month_report');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there - please expand your question with a bit more context!

Comment: i have number like  in database  total_sale 1)12,478.  2)20, 3)10 but it return 42 only

Comment: 12,478 here 478 values can't calculate

Comment: Sounds like your Column in the Database is type of Varchar, not integer.

Comment: thanks  MackieeE for quck reply  it is varchar but still

Comment: It shouldn't be varchar - if you are summing values, it needs to be a numeric field type - an integer or decimal.

Comment: if i make it integer then it can't save in database only 12 is saving . but my requirement is 12,478

Comment: please help me it's not  working still thanks in advance

Comment: Before you insert into the database, you need to remove the comma!

Comment: don't have any function in codeigniter -in php present exploade()

Comment: to be more clear about data type use "var_dump($a);" to check if variable having integer or not

Comment: @user6171329 This'll be suffice [Converting Formatted int to int](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11026674/292735)

Comment: Thanksssss   MackieeE realy your a great person

Comment: what you want to sum..! column name?

Comment: @user6171329 Happy it worked =)

Answer (score 0):

if you want ot select sum. make like documentation
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

```
$this->db->select('(SELECT SUM(payments.amount) FROM payments WHERE payments.invoice_id=4') AS amount_paid', FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [NumberFormatter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) class to parse a locale-specific number.

but for using it you need **PHP version >= 5.3** And **`intl` extension version >= 1.0**

if you have it, uncomment this line `extension=php_intl.dll` from `php.ini` if it is commented.

and use it as below example:

```
<?php
    $num1 = '12,478.76';
    $nf = new NumberFormatter("en_EN", NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);

    var_dump($nf->parse($num1));

    // output: float(12478.76) 
   // it will automatically parse int, double,float etc.
?>
```