# String replace in PHP

Tags: php

I have replaced comma ,   buy using  str_replace(); following is the code of it

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE lc_status='Yes' ORDER BY file_no DESC");
$tmp=0;
$tmp1 = 0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
$tmp +=str_replace(',','', $row['jpy_value']);
$tmp1 +=str_replace(',','',$row['lkr_value']);
```

Now I can get the total value of the column. but total value is coming without the comma.
Ex:   250000

how can i replace the comma back to normal number format.
i would be very glad if someone can help me with it

Comment: use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: `$tmp += intval(str_replace(",", "", $row['jpy_value']));`

Comment: You can use the [`NumberFormatter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) for a cleaner solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/11026779/2290008

Comment: thx for your help.. got an idea about numformat and numberformatter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `intval()` to convert the string to number and `str_replace` to replace the `,`.

```
$tmp += intval(str_replace(",", "", $row['jpy_value']));
$tmp1 += intval(str_replace(',','',$row['lkr_value']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the `number_format()` function. Example for your number `250000`:

```
<?php
$number = 250000;
echo number_format ($number, 2, ",", ".");

# Output: 250.000,00
?>
```

The output is `250.000,00` because I have set the following settings in order:

1. The number (250000)
2. Total decimals (Places 2 decimals after your number)
3. The separator for the decimal point.
4. The thousands separator.

Read more about [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

Comment: thx for your answer . but it's not giving the answer i needed.  after using this code calculation gets wrong.  it checkes

Comment: Alright haha, if it worked, you may want to accept this answer as solved if you want to @user3431701 :-)