# convert large values of string to number laravel. (int) gives wrong value

Tags: php, laravel, numbers

When I do:

```
$var = (int)('5000');
dd($var);  //outputs 5000
```

```
$query = Mymodel::find($id);
dd($query->loan_amount); //outputs "1,040,000.00"
```

Also:

```
$var = (int)($query->loan_amount);
dd($var);  //outputs 1
```

And finally:

```
$query = Mymodel::find($id);
dd($query->loan_amount); //outputs the picture below
```

[image]

May I know why? And how do I fix the large numbers?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, what version of Laravel/PHP are you using?

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's literally the string `'1040000'`? No other symbols and none of the zeros are letters "O"?

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.8.36 || PHP 7.3.9 @kerbholz

Comment: Please check your input it exactly `1040000`.

Comment: The string `1,040,000.00` will be converted to `1` when casting to integer because of the comma - it interprets it as a decimal separator.

Comment: @El_Vanja I just edited the question. Your questions opened my eyes.

Comment: If the query object internally holds a string with a non-formatted numeric value (`1040000`), but outputs `->loan_amount` as `1,040,000.00`, then some sort of magic get has to be implemented, which formats it. And that formatted number will be cast to 1.

Comment: Add a method to the query class which returns the amount as a simple integer if you are able to edit that class. If not, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11026779/4205384) might prove useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Model Collection` has `104000` But output shows `1,040,000.00`. So you might have used `Accessor / Mutator`.

You can try this to convert,

```
// remove `,` then convert.
$loan_amount = (int) (str_ireplace(',', '', $query->loan_amount));
dd($loan_amount);
```

**Another way**

Standard way to format `model attributes` in `laravel` is [accessors & mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#introduction), Please check it out.